# "for" loop and getting the number of letters of each item in the list

Tags: python

Given the list below, loop through it using a `for` loop with the aim of getting the number of letters of each item in the list.

```
darasa=['projector','computer','students','laptops']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for a in darasa:
    print(a,len(a))
```

Comment: What is the point in the dictionary in printed output?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, straight-foward solution:

```
for word in darasa:
    print(word, len(word))
```

Comment: ya this works kind of but does not specify which number  points to which letter

Comment: @RuchiRathod what exactly do you mean? You can also print the word itself in the loop.